# Elastic Search Response JSON sanitization

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

General elasticsearch question:

I get a good response where the `_source` is formatted as:

`{
    "Message": {
        "S": "This item has changed"
    },
    "Id": {
        "N": "101"
   }
}`

I want to convert this to

`{
    "Message": "This item has changed",
    "Id": 101,
}`

I want to sanitize the response severside so that the response is only what the front end needs and there isn't any additional processing necessary.

So I suppose I can map over the object and create a switch statement for all the different types elasticsearch supports. But is there a "standard" way for approaching this problem?  Feels like this would be a pretty common use case and am assuming there might be a better solution out there.

Has anyone run into this before and found a good solution for it?

Comment: garbage in garbage out! Why don't you index the same structure you that you want to get out in the first place?

Comment: This is my first crack at elasticsearch.  So chances are I just don't know everything it can do! :) . I had set my index to just the id as that's how it is in the table this search is indexing.   If I index the whole object as you suggest would this problem be fixed?